# file_get_contents not working for some domains

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents

As a part of the requirement I need to find out whether a domain is parked or not. As there is no efficient way to find out this, I'm going to check the DOM for phrases like "Buy this domain", "may be for sale".. etc.

I found some parked domains which can be accessed through browser, but cannot able to get them using `file_get_contents`.

Example

```
$url = 'http://buythisdomain.com/'
$get = file_get_contents($url);
```

For the above got the following message at output.

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://buythisdomain.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

But able to access the same URL via browser.I tried `fopen` method too, but same result. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The site is probably blocking requests that don't contain any browser signature, perhaps because they don't want you accessing them from a script

Comment: @MarkBaker oh okay. Thanks. so is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, create a `filestream context` as shown in @Brain's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many sites, not only parked domains use some mechanism to block basic requests without valid browser headers.

Try to use stream context that send that required headers like a browser like this

```
$url = "http://buythisdomain.com/"
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' =>
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" .
            "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n".
            "Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=10\r\n",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
        'user_agent' => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.66 Safari/535.11",
        "ignore_errors" => true,
        "timeout" => 3
    )
));
file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: Just need small confirmation, It's *not* working for some domains ex: `http://makeoffer.in`' Getting 404 Not Found response at firebug. but it is directly accessable through browser. any idea?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan I've tested that domain also, works fine. If you get a 404 in the browser than it's not because of the script because your are having that 404 in your browser? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: yeah!, I think that domain has meta refresh in it's DOM. so when I test my code at browser, getting first response HTML like ` <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/Zm9yY2VTUg">` then immediate response became  like `http://localhost:81/glp?r=&u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A81%2Fparse%2Ftest.php` so I think that causes object not found issue.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Sure that sounds reasonable, but the script should work as expected.

Comment: I am still getting "Not Found". The url I am trying to fetch is `https://www.auction.com/residential/CA/active_lt/land_pt/resi_sort_v2_st/y_nbs/`. What can be going wrong? Please help